# Align text inside div on window resize

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to create a login page, and it's starting to look good, but when I resized the window, the "[] Remember me" field jumped out of the div:

[image: out of div]

I want it to always stay like this:

[image: wanted]

I've made a demo of this login page here: [Jfiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9cmuqbL1/4/)

**IMPORTANT:** The width in the example has been set to `10%` just to show what I mean, inside the class `.div_center`. Remove this to get normal responsive size.

Comment: remove fixed height of`.div_center`

Comment: Links to jsfiddle must be accompanied by the code in the question itself, please don't ignore the rules of SO - marking a couple of classes as code to get around the rule is not acceptable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your .div_center you have provided a height of 370px. But due to the margin incmoing from top, your checkbox is being pushed outside the box.
Here's a tweak, just set height to fit-content, and the box would always keep hold of it's contents.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `clamp` in font-size,
ex: `font-size: clamp(1rem, 2.5vw, 2rem);`
Go through the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp()
or you try to do with media query